# How to retrieve value from returned object in php?

Tags: php, neo4jphp

How to retrieve value from a complicated object structure in php? I know using '->' operator we can access the value but I am very confused in the object I am returned with. From the object returned, I want to fetch the **character** value. How do i do that?
I am using [Neo4jPHP](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp) and trying to execute a cypher query "MATCH (n) RETURN distinct keys(n)" to return all distinct property keys. After doing a var_dump of the row object, the partial output is shown below.
[image: see in image about the object structure]

**Edit**:- My edited code after following Mikkel's advice:-

```
$keyquery="MATCH (n) RETURN distinct keys(n)"; 
$querykey=new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $keyquery);
$resultkey = $querykey->getResultSet();
foreach ($resultkey as $row) 
{
for($i=0;$i<count($row[0]);$i++)
{
echo $row[0][$i]; // returns all the property keys from the Row object
}
}
```

Comment: It's a protected field "raw" you can't access it.

Comment: That is a protected property, not public. You can only access it internally inside that class or by parsing the var_dump. Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: What if you do `var_dump($myobject[0][0]);`?

Comment: Thanks Mikkel for the reply. var_dump($myobject[0][0]) works but with a small error as shown here http://imgur.com/l4jwRqA. Another problem is in some iteration where there are 2 property keys as shown here http://imgur.com/4dSn74G, the above method only returns one key. I think I am almost there but slight logical issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the object property directly as it was declared as [protected](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) (only accessible from within the class or an inheriting class).

However, in such a case, the developer has usually added an object method or overloading function that allows you to access the information you're looking for. Taking a peek at [the source](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/blob/master/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Query/Row.php), it looks like you should be able to access the data you're looking for using either:

```
// this works because the class implements Iterator
foreach ($myobject as $row) {
    echo $row['keys(n)']; // outputs "character"
}
```

or:

```
// this works because the class implements ArrayAccess
// don't ask me why they put keys and values in different arrays ('columns' and 'raw')
echo $myobject[0]['keys(n)']; // outputs "character"
```

Comment: Error: Object of class Everyman\Neo4j\Query\Row could not be converted to string

Comment: Applying some common logic, I traversed in the myobject[0] array and am able to get all the property keys successfully. I am pasting my code in the question (i should have done that earlier) and might be accordingly you can edit your answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are looking for is protected and not accessible,

1. try find object class and add function to retrieve the value.
2. use regular expression to extract the portion, which is not recommended:
   /\'character\'(length\=(.*?))/

Comment: "character" is the string he is trying to get back. Unlikely that it would show up in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you look the class [Row](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/blob/master/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Query/Row.php) you will find out that you can access it treating the object like an array.

```
$character = $myRow[0];
```

Comment: It's a protected @leggendario

Comment: I think we cannot directly access as array.
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Everyman\Neo4j\Query\Row could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the object you dumped [here](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/blob/master/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Query/Row.php), you can see that the object is implementing \Iterator, \Countable, \ArrayAccess, which means you can basically treat it like an array. The underlying data source is the protected $raw.

```
$queryResult = ...;

foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
   echo $row['character'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. By the way since its a object that is returned to me, when i try your bove method I get an error like:-
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Everyman\Neo4j\Query\Row could not be converted to string

Comment: $keyquery="MATCH (n) RETURN distinct keys(n)";  //return all UNIQUE PROPERTY KEYS in the dataset
$querykey=new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $keyquery);
$resultkey = $querykey->getResultSet();
foreach ($resultkey as $row) 
{
 echo $row['character'];
}